# How to resolve request timeout

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am writing API to upload large Excel file and do validation and dump data to DB, but whenever I am trying to upload large file I got Error Gateway Timeout 504.
So is there any way to avoid timeout and wait client until server send response.
I am using java spring and angular.

Comment: For such a use-case, you should generally use an asynchronous workflow: 1. upload the file; 2. get back an immediate response containing some processing job ID: the server generates a job and starts processing in a separate thread. 3. poll the server until the status of the job goes from "running" to "finished".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of uploading large excel file, u can try converting excel to csv and then doing operations before uploading. It may solve the issue.